Historical Delta Airlines Tail numbers (2012) - Where to find?
I was looking for the tail numbers of 2 flights.  The only records I could find were the US Transportation data for domestic flights but I could not find any International Delta Airlines Flights.
The flights are:
Delta DL19 from London Heathrow to Detroit Wayne county on 15th June 2012 departing 09:02 landed at 12:23
Delta DL46 from Atlanta Hartsfield Jackson to London Heathrow on 25th June 2012 departing 17:59 landed at 07:36 (on 26th)
Which databases can I look at?

This question belongs to the passenger area of aviation, you should ask at Travel.SE.

FlightAware likely has the data, but free access only gives you the past three months of a given flight number.  You'll need paid access to get at the full history of a flight.  FlightRadar24 is another site with similar capabilities.
